# Green's function for a dielectric with a charge

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electrostatics, boundary-conditions, dielectric, greens-functions

Suppose there are two infinite planes, one in $z=a$ and the other in $z=b$, with $a<b$. Between the planes, there is a dielectric medium with constant $\epsilon_1$. The differential equation for the electric potential is (inside the medium):

$$\nabla^2 \Phi =-\dfrac{\rho}{\epsilon_1},$$

but $\rho=0$ in this case. Now, if I put a charge $q_1$ in the dielectric, the differential equation is

$$\nabla^2 \Phi =-\dfrac{q_1 \delta(\mathbf r- \mathbf{r'})}{\epsilon_1}.$$

I want to solve this problem with the Green's function method, which means, I first find the Green's function and then the electric potential. Without the charge, the differential equation for the Green's function is:

\begin{equation}
\nabla^{2}G_1=-\dfrac{\delta(\mathbf r- \mathbf{r'})}{\epsilon_1} \tag{1}.
\end{equation}

This can be 'easily' solved. With the charge, the differential equation is (I think):
\begin{equation}
\nabla^{2}G_2=-\dfrac{q_1\delta(\mathbf r- \mathbf{r'})}{\epsilon_1} \tag{2}.
\end{equation}

If I assume Dirichlet boundary conditions, both $G_1$ and $G_2$ would be the same (again, I think). Does the form of $G_2$ change if I put three, four or more charges inside the dielectric?

Comment: Why is this question off-topic? Should I _show some effort to work through this problem_?

Comment: Now? Is it good?

Comment: It needs to ask about a specific concept, too. Showing work is secondary (see the linked policy for mode details)

Comment: @Manishearth Now, is it clearer than before?